# Present UIViewController from Side

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to present a UIViewController from the side.
The only thing that Present Modal can do is Verticle Slide in.

Any body have any ideas about this?

Let me know' thanks

Comment: You really should accept some answers! A accept ratio of 0% is pretty bad and it will stop people from helping you.

Comment: Too true, I'm feeling festive though :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be anal about the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller), its really the View your moving and not the controller.

I would recommended the way of doing this would be to use a navigation controller, it's animation is a horizontal slide by default and you get a navigation stack for free- this means that you have back buttons auto generated and, title and button properties that you can set, although these can be hidden easily is desired.

Using a navigation controller:

create a UINavigationsController property in your parent controller, syth, alloc and init it appropriately. Then you can load the controllers in in any order you want and it looks after the navigation.

[Here](http://www.matthewcasey.co.uk/2010/05/23/tutorial-introducing-uinavigationcontroller-part-1/) is a good tutorial on NavControllers (usually they are used with UITableViewControllers but don't have to be)

Peng's example is an animation and I should note that it removes the parent view (and depending on your design might not **just** remove the 'currentView' - as your/a top view might be a subView) so if your navigating back you would have to handle this yourself.

Comment: Uhm... you are anal about the MVC pattern?

Comment: Just making the point that you don't present a 'Controller' 'from the side'

Answer (score 2):

I did this and it worked, though I don't know if there is a more official way to do it (UIVIewAimationTransition doesn't have a slide option):

```
    UIView *currentView = self.view;
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

[currentView removeFromSuperview];

CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

Comment: Say I wanted to Remove the View, and make it look like it Came back from the right. Would I just change the Subtype?

Comment: Yep the subtype will change the direction of animation.

Comment: You'll need to add the following to the top of your viewcontroller:

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Answer (score 0):

I just gave this answer to another SO question that was very similar, but here it is again, in case folks looking end-up here, instead.

All of the ViewControllers in my app inherit from `MyViewController` which, in addition to some other default behaviours, has this property:

```
@property(readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL slideFromSide;
```

And this code:

```
- (void) presentViewController: (UIViewController*) vc animated: (BOOL) flag completion: (void (^)(void)) completion
{
    BOOL slideIn = NO;
    if ([vc isKindOfClass: [MyViewController class]])
    {
        MyViewController *svc = (MyViewController*) vc;
        slideIn = svc.slideFromSide;
    }

    if (slideIn)
    {
        [self addChildViewController: vc];
        [self.view addSubview: vc.view];

        CGRect frame = vc.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width;
        vc.view.frame = frame;

        frame.origin.x = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.33
                         animations: ^{
                             vc.view.frame = frame;
                         }
         ];
    }
    else
    {
        [super presentViewController: vc animated: flag completion: completion];
    }
}


- (IBAction) backAction: (id) sender
{
    if (_slideFromSide)
    {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width;
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.33
                         animations: ^{
                             self.view.frame = frame;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [self removeFromParentViewController];
                         }
         ];
    }
    else
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
    }
}
```

Then, in the ViewControllers where I want to slide-in, I have:

```
- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil bundle: nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.slideFromSide = YES;
        // Whatever else you want to do
    }

    return self;
}
```

Calling a new ViewController is just like normal:

```
WhateverViewController *vc = [WhateverViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
[self presentViewController: vc animated: YES completion: nil];
```